# c++ how to compare a string to a dynamic structure string using pointers?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have to code a method of a class in C++ that shows me all the attributes of a class when they give me only the name. For example, I have a class 'Team' with a_name, a_goals and a_points. So when they give me a string with the name, I have to compare it to my dynamic structure and find the team with the same name to show it. I have this code:

```
void Classificacio::mostrar(string nom) const {
    Equip eq;
    Node* i=a_inici;
    bool trobat=false;
    while(!trobat && i!=NULL) {
        if(nom.compare(i->a_equip.NomEquip())==0) trobat=true;
        else i=i->seg;
    }
    if(trobat==true) eq=i->a_equip;
    cout << eq << endl;
}
```

NomEquip() is a method that returns the team name.
But it doesn't work. Every time I try to execute it with the debugger, it stops in the line with the if. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Wanted to translate it to english but I forgot some things, just copy/pasted it this time.

Comment: What do you mean "the debugger stops"?  As if there's a breakpoint there?  Or does the program crash?

Comment: You're not using the argument `name` anywhere in the function, unless there is a typo in there.  In which case, copy and paste your code, don't type it here from memory. Otherwise you waste everyone's time debugging code that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Yes sorry fixed it now. And the program crashes

Comment: Side note: As a general rule, program in English. Some people (like us) may end up having to read it.

Comment: Where's the definition and initialization for `a_inici`?

Comment: Classificacio::Classificacio() {
    a_inici=NULL;
    a_final=NULL;
}

Comment: `i` isn't valid, is about the only thing that's left at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility of crashing in the line:

```
if (trobat == true) eq=i->a_equip;
```

Because you check for 'i!=NULL`in the`while`loop.  One of the terminating conditions of the`while`loop is that`i == NULL`.

Assuming the `while` loop was terminated because `i == NULL`, your `if` statement will dereference a NULL pointer which is undefined behavior.

**Edit 1:**
If it crashes at `if (nom.compare(i->a_equip.NomEquip()) == 0)`, and we know `i` is valid, it leads that the `NomEquip` function is a leading culprint.

Change your `while` loop to:

```
while (...)
{
  std::string nom_equip = i->a_equip.NomEquip();
  if (nom == nom_equip)
//...
}
```

Now place breakpoint at the `std::string` line and step into the function to trace it.

Comment: It never gets to that line because it crashes in this one:
if(nom.compare(i->a_equip.NomEquip())==0) trobat=true;

Comment: @p.bosch: see Edit 1 of my answer.

Comment: @p.bosch: Please edit your question to show the class of `a_equip`, especially the `NomEquip` method.